# WYGWAM Content Templates Blank

Tags: wygwam

I've successfully used WYGWAM (CK Editor) Styles before but I cannot get the Templates to work. I have a relative path in my WYGWAM settings like so:

[image]

And I'm just getting this:

[image]

I have the following code in my "wygwam_templates.js" file:

```
    // Register a template definition set named "default".
CKEDITOR.addTemplates( 'default',
{
// The name of the subfolder that contains the preview images of the templates.
//imagesPath : CKEDITOR.getUrl( CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath( 'templates' ) + 'templates/images/' ),

// Template definitions.
templates :
    [
        {
            title: 'Insert Location Map',
            description: 'Using this will add the interactive map to this page',
            html:
                '<img src="/images/layout/locations_map.jpg" usemap="#locations" />' +
                '<map name="locations" id="locations">' +
                    '<area id="corporate" shape="rect" coords="46,97,170,136" href="#" />' +
                    '<area id="brazil" shape="rect" coords="207,246,257,277" href="#" />' +
                    '<area id="uruguay" shape="rect" coords="202,299,265,324" href="#" />' +
                    '<area id="germany" shape="rect" coords="293,76,354,105" href="#" />' +
                    '<area id="italy" shape="rect" coords="350,102,392,119" href="#" />' +
                    '<area id="india" shape="rect" coords="478,158,524,178" href="#" />' +
                    '<area id="china" shape="rect" coords="551,140,595,163" href="#" />' +
                '</map>'
        }


    ]
```

});

I love the ideas of the Templates but for the life of me I can't get it to work. Any help would be great!

I'm using EE 2.72 and Wygwam 3.2.1

Comment: I have also tried replacing the "ckeditor" folder per this forum post http://get-simple.info/forums/showthread.php?tid=1976 with the "full version" of CKEditor to no avail :(

Answer (score 1):

Okay you must set "template_files" to reference your JS file. You also must update your CKEditor JS files as seen here: http://get-simple.info/forums/showthread.php?tid=1976